# Static assertion if possible, dynamic assertion otherwise?

Tags: c++, static-assert

Let's say I have a template function that takes an integer and a const reference to an instance of type T. Now depending on the integer, only some T's are acceptible, otherwise an exception is thrown at runtime.

If all uses of this function would use constant integers, it would be possible to make the int a template parameter and use a static assertion to check if it is acceptable. So instead of `func(1,c)` one would use `func<1>(c)` and would gain compile-time type checking. Is there any way to write `func(1,c)` and still keep the compile-time check, while also being able to write `func(i,c)` and use a dynamic assertion? The goal is to make it transparent to the developer. It would simply be great to add this safety without bothering the developers about things like compile-time constants. They'd probably only remember that `func(1,c)` always works and use that, avoiding the check.

**How can I define a function with a static assertion whenever possible and a dynamic assertion otherwise?**

---

The following code shows the solution for GCC by **Ivan Shcherbakov**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

template<typename T>
void __attribute__((always_inline)) func(const int& i, const T& t);

void compile_time_error_() __attribute__((__error__ ("assertion failed")));

template<>
  void __attribute__((always_inline))
  func(const int& i, const float& t)
{
    do {
        if (i != 0) {
            if (__builtin_constant_p(i)) compile_time_error_();
            std::cerr << "assertion xzy failed" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    } while (0);
    func_impl<float>(i,t);
}
```

This will only allow the combination of i=0 and T=float. For other combinations a good way would be creating a Macro that produces the code of `template<> func(const int& i, const T& t)` with T and i != 0 replaced.

Comment: @Linuxios static_assert needs a constant-expression. I can do a static assertion without C++11 if I always have a constant-expression. The problem is doing a dynamic assertion otherwise instead of failing to compile.

Comment: I get it! I'll think about that.

Comment: I don't think it is possible (or rather, reasonably possible) to write the same expression for compile-time constants and runtime variables. The closest would be the template to accept a compile-time constant integer.

Comment: @jrok The const reference is simply a promise not to change the value referenced by it, it doesn't guarantee you a constant-expression. So this doesn't work out.

Comment: I think this question goes much deeper, to how to bridge the gap between compile and runtime execution. Maybe there's a solution to this in `constexpr` in C++11 (but it sets its own limits)?

Comment: @Tar: Would it be acceptable for the programmer to write `func<1>(c)` when they use a literal, or must it be possible to write `func(1,c)` and get the compile-time check?

Comment: @outis The goal is to make it transparent to the developer. If it isn't possible, I'll use Ivan Shcherbakov's solution on GCC (and maybe clang, if Hugo is right) and additionally add func<1>(c) for use when the developer knows that he uses a constant-expresssion. It would simply be great to add this safety without bothering the developers about things like compile-time constants. They'd probably only remember that func(1,c) always works and use that, avoiding the check. ;)

Comment: @Tar: do you have suitable sample implementations of `func(int, const T&)` illustrating the assertions?

Comment: `#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
template<typename T> void __attribute__((always_inline)) func(const int& i, const T& t);
void compile_time_error_() __attribute__((__error__ ("assertion failed")));
template<> void __attribute__((always_inline)) func(const int& i, const float& t) {
    do {
        if(!(i==0)) {
            if (__builtin_constant_p(i)) compile_time_error_();
            std::cerr << "assertion xzy failed" << std::endl;
            exit(1);
        }
    } while (0);
    func_impl<float>(i,t);
}`

Comment: @outis: the above allows 0/float only. Add in the C preprocessor for code generation (for id/type pairs) and checking if the whole using-GCC-attributes-and-builtins makes sense (by checking for `__GNUC__`) and the whole thing works well :)

Comment: @Tar: Is that an example of where you were starting from, or your final solution? I was looking for the former to [fill out the question](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints). In general, please respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a Q&A site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions. Lastly, code isn't very readable in comments.

Comment: @outis: But the "implementation of `func(int, const T&)` illustrating the assertions" is the **solution** not the question. Shouldn't the solution be found in the answers section instead of being editted into middle of the question? And if there is a way of sending PMs, I haven't found it yet. So how else could I have answered you without editting chat into the question?

Comment: @tar: the solution should indeed be in the answer and not the question. Note that I wasn't asking for the solution, hence my confusion at your response, my question about which you posted and my clarification about what I was looking for. SO isn't a forum, so it doesn't have a PM function. My earlier comments were requests for clarifications, not chat, so you don't have to respond to them directly; there's no need to edit chatter into the question. In this case, you should edit the question to provide appropriate sample code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, if you're using GCC, you can use a dirty hack, but it will only work when function inlining is enabled (-O1 or more):

```
void my_error() __attribute__((__error__ ("Your message here")));

template <typename T1, typename T2> struct compare_types 
{
    enum {Equals = 0};
};

template <typename T1> struct compare_types<T1,T1> 
{
    enum {Equals = 1};
};

template <typename Type> __attribute__((always_inline)) void func(int a, Type &x)
{
    if (__builtin_constant_p(a))
    {
        if (a == 1 && compare_types<Type,char>::Equals)
            my_error();
    }
}
```

In this case when `a == 1` and `Type` is `char`, you'll get an error. Here's an example that will trigger it:

```
int main()
{
    char x;
    func(1, x);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that this example heavily relies on the gcc-specific `__builtin_constant_p()` function and won't work with other compilers!

Comment: Ah, this is great! Is there a similar function for clang?

Comment: Quickly googling for "__builtin_constant_p LLVM" says "no", but maybe you will be more lucky. It's heavily used in fcntl2.h, so I would look there to see how LLVM handles it.

Comment: Didn't research, but using it with clang++ succeeded here.

Comment: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtins says that clang supports `__builtin_constant_p`, so this solution is nearly perfect. I doubt it's possible in a portable manner.

Comment: Yes, such names are reserved for the library. Library source is a great educational tool, but reading nothing else is hazardous to your style!

Answer (score 2):

Let me paraphrase question to be more accurate in my answer:

> Can runtime assert **sometimes** report errors on compile time.

Gcc can, but only on some optimization level and error message is
very uninformative. Clang itself can't (no error attribute), but do
not forget about clang **analyzer**.
Analyzer can report some runtime errors like dereferencing null pointer.

So here is an idea and simple test of 'smart' runtime assert:

```
#include <cstdlib> // std::abort

#if !defined(__clang__) && defined(__GNUC__)
// clang emulates gcc
# define GCC_COMPILER 1
#else
# define GCC_COMPILER 0
#endif

#if GCC_COMPILER
void assertion_failed_message() __attribute__((__error__("assertion failed")));
#endif

inline void smart_assert(bool condition) {
#if GCC_COMPILER
  // gcc is very 'sensitive', it must be first code lines in this function
  if (__builtin_constant_p(condition) && !condition) {
    assertion_failed_message();
  }
#endif

  if (condition) {
    // Ok
    return;
  }

#if defined(__clang_analyzer__)
  enum {
    ASSERTION_FAILED = 0xdeadfull
  };
  int *a = nullptr;
  *a = ASSERTION_FAILED;
#endif

  // Implement some standart error, like abort
  std::abort();
}

void test_condition_2(bool condition) {
  smart_assert(condition);
}

void test_condition_1(bool condition) {
  test_condition_2(condition);
}

void test_condition_0(bool condition) {
  test_condition_1(condition);
}

int main() {
  test_condition_0(0==1);
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Gcc report error at O2 optimization level, it's good. But report message
is in main function, and don't leave any information
about test_condition_{0,1,2}.

Clang analyzer report error and if you use Xcode, you can see all path
from main to smart_assert:
[image: clang_analyzer_report]

**P.S.** clang analyzer is not perfect, so if you try test_condition_0(argc),
no error will be reported (truely runtime check), but if you try
test_condition_0(argc==1), false positive will be reported.

Comment: This might be "smart" but it's also disgusting. +1 anyway, but ... eurgh.