# An assert macro which expands to static_assert when possible?

Tags: c++, assert, static-assert

I have some generic code that needs to run an assertion over the result of a member function. This member function may be `constexpr`, or it may not be.

```
template<typename T>
void foo(T t) {
  assert(t.member_function() == 10);
}
```

Because `t.member_function()` *might* be a constant expression, I'm wondering if it's possible to be treated as a `static_assert` in such cases, but otherwise default to a normal `assert`. Is this possible?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/11441302/560648. Not sure it's that applicable though.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6939103/560648 is closer, and [it says the answer is "no"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6941680/560648).

Comment: [stackoverflow.com/questions/18648069](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648069/g-doesnt-compile-constexpr-function-with-assert-in-it) is even more close and says "yes but"

Answer (score 2):

This is a slightly crazy solution.

Uncomment the `Const c; foo(c);` line and you'll see that it won't compile.  This is the compile-time assert.

It requires [variable length arrays](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html), and maybe other compiler specific stuff.  I'm on g++-4.6.

The size of the array is either 0 or -1, depending on whether the member function returns 10.  So if this can be computed at compile-time, then the compile realizes it's a non-variable length array, and that it has negative size.  The negative size allows it to complain.  Otherwise, it falls through to a conventional assert.

*Please note: I'm getting some core dump with the Runtime version just after the runtime assertion fails.  Maybe it doesn't like trying to `free` an array with negative size. Update: I'm getting core dumps with any assertion failure, even `int main() {assert (1==2);}`. Is this normal?*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
using namespace std;

struct Const {
        constexpr int member_function() { return 9; }
};
struct Runtime {
                  int member_function() { return 9; }
};

template<typename T>
void foo(T t) {
        if(0) {  // so it doesn't actually run any code to malloc/free the vla
            int z[(t.member_function()==10)-1]; // fails at compile-time if necessary
        }
        assert(t.member_function()==10);
}


int main() {
        //Const c; foo(c);
        Runtime r; foo(r);
}
```

Comment: cool hack. although i'd have assumed the compiler be smart enough to directly ignore the if(0). lol like what if a constexpr of false were in an if statement. but i guess if might try compile what's inside with the constexpr creating that -1 size array, which fails the assertion.