# g++ doesn't compile constexpr function with assert in it

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, assert, constexpr

```
template<typename T> constexpr inline 
T getClamped(const T& mValue, const T& mMin, const T& mMax) 
{ 
     assert(mMin < mMax); // remove this line to successfully compile
     return mValue < mMin ? mMin : (mValue > mMax ? mMax : mValue); 
}
```

> *error*: **body of constexpr function** 'constexpr T getClamped(const T&, const T&, const T&) [with T = long unsigned int]' **not a return-statement**

Using `g++ 4.8.1`. `clang++ 3.4` doesn't complain.

Who is right here? Any way I can make `g++` compile the code without using macros?

Comment: You can probably use `static_assert`...

Comment: For future reference: please provide a simple main function that triggers the error in question.

Comment: @MatsPetersson: what if the `constexpr` fails and the function is executed at runtime?

Comment: Surely that is not "allowed" (that is, the compiler should not allow you to form a call to `getClamped` where the inputs aren't constants - so at least the `static_assert` should fire if the inputs are "wrong way around", even if it can't sort out the clamping at compile-time [although I don't see why it shouldn't be able to do that too].

Comment: Very good question +1 because you have uncovered a compiler bug. Very badly written -1. Makes +0. @Vittorio, me and a some others like to confirm an example via copy&paste&compile. Additionally, imagine you where not using `#include <assert.h>` but something else very fancy, it may make a difference.

Comment: @PatrickFromberg, should I make a minimal example and post it here?

Comment: @Vittorio, no but next time please. In your case the compile options where actually more important as others pointed out. After thinking about your idea I am tempted to undefine `constexpr` depending on NDEBUG set or not.

Comment: Alright, sorry for writing the question poorly. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

GCC is right.  However, there is a relatively simple workaround:

```
#include "assert.h"

inline void assert_helper( bool test ) {
  assert(test);
}
inline constexpr bool constexpr_assert( bool test ) {
  return test?true:(assert_helper(test),false);
}

template<typename T> constexpr
inline T getClamped(const T& mValue, const T& mMin, const T& mMax)
{
  return constexpr_assert(mMin < mMax), (mValue < mMin ? mMin : (mValue > mMax ? mMax : mValue));
}
```

where we abuse the comma operator, twice.

The first time because we want to have an `assert` that, when `true`, can be called from a `constexpr` function.  The second, so we can chain two functions into a single `constexpr` function.

As a side benefit, if the `constexpr_assert` expression cannot be verified to be `true` at compile time, then the `getClamped` function is not `constexpr`.

The `assert_helper` exists because the contents of `assert` are implementation defined when `NDEBUG` is true, so we cannot embed it into an expression (it could be a statement, not an expression).  It also guarantees that a failed `constexpr_assert` fails to be `constexpr` even if `assert` is `constexpr` (say, when `NDEBUG` is false).

A downside to all of this is that your assert fires not at the line where the problem occurs, but 2 calls deeper.

Comment: Equivalent to `test && assert( test )`, which I would find more idiomatic.

Comment: @Potatoswatter No, it isn't.  When `NDEBUG` is undefined, `assert(test)` is `void(0)`, and your expression is illegal.  When `NDEBUG` is defined, `assert(test)` is completely implementation defined.  So `test && assert(test)` may or may not be valid code that may or may not work.

Comment: Ah, sorry. Good deal :)

Comment: The separate function `assert_helper` is not needed: C++11 19.3/2 describes the header `<cassert>`: "The contents are the same as the Standard C library header `<assert.h>`. See also: ISO C 7.2." N1570 (almost C11) 7.2.1.1/2 states: "The `assert` macro puts diagnostic tests into programs; it expands to a void expression." so the body of `getClamped` can be simply `return assert(mMin < mMax), (mValue < mMin ? mMin : (mValue > mMax ? mMax : mValue));`.

Comment: @Casey not quite: we have no guarantee from any of that that `assert(true)` is a valid part of a `constexpr`.  So we have to evaluate `mMin < mMax`, and *only if false* can we call `assert`.  Ie, we don't need `assert_helper`, but we still technically need `constexpr_assert` for full portability.

Comment: Is there any way to modify this to create an assertion macro that can trigger at compile-time when a `constexpr` function is called with an improper argument, but which can also trigger at run-time when the `constexpr` function is called at run-time? Essentially something that behaves like `static_assert` when `constexpr` functions are actually evaluated during compilation but `assert` if/when the body of the function is actually linked?

Comment: @KyleStrand http://ericniebler.com/2014/09/27/assert-and-constexpr-in-cxx11/ this is probably what you need

Comment: @oliora Wow, that lambda trick is madness. Anyway, I didn't realize that `assert` actually *can* be used in a `constexpr` function in C++14, which seems like a crucial thing to know. In fact, I'll add that as an answer.

Comment: @oliora ...except, bizarrely, I can't get his `throw` trick to actually work for me with `g++`.... `error: expression '<throw-expression>' is not a constant-expression`

Comment: @KyleStrand that's what I come up as a cross-compiler c++11 solution https://gist.github.com/oliora/928424f7675d58fadf49c70fdba70d2f

Comment: @oliora Actually, the `throw` trick works fine as long as it's part of a ternary expression; I must have screwed that up yesterday.

Comment: @KyleStrand using throw is a good solution if you ok with exception in release version. I didn't want it so I used assert.

Comment: @oliora Though of course as Niebler points out, using `noexcept` is essentially equivalent to having an `assert` that is not suppressed for release builds.

Comment: @oliora I've gone ahead and written up an answer, crediting you and Niebler.

Comment: @oliora FYI I've now written [an answer to another question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42659084/1858225) again relying heavily on your code and the link you've provided.

Answer (score 5):

As of C++14, this is no longer an issue; `g++` with the `-std=c++14` flag compiles and runs your code just fine.

There are three drawbacks:

- As noted in your question, this **does not work** in C++11.
- The `assert` will, of course, never by triggered at compile time. Even adding a `static_assert` with the same condition won't work, since `mMin` and `mMax` are not considered constant expressions.
- Moreover, because the `assert` isn't triggered at compile time, but the function is `constexpr`, if the condition is *false* but the expression *is* evaluated at compile time (e.g. `constexpr auto foo = getClamped(1,2,0);`), the `assert` will **never** fire--meaning that the incorrect function arguments will not be caught.

In a comment, user oliora links to an [interesting blog post by Eric Niebler](http://ericniebler.com/2014/09/27/assert-and-constexpr-in-cxx11/) that describes multiple approaches that work in C++11 **and** can be triggered while compiling or at runtime as appropriate.

In short, the strategies are:

- `throw` an exception; to make it uncatchable (i.e. more like an `assert`), mark the `constexpr` function `nothrow`

  - Niebler does not call this out in his post, but the `throw` expression **must** be wrapped in some kind of larger logical expression that is *only* evaluated if the condition being `assert`ed is `false`, such as a ternary expression (which is what Niebler uses in his example). A standalone `if (condition) throw <exception>;` statement will **not** be permitted, even in C++14.
  - Niebler also fails to note that, unlike `assert`, this approach **does not** depend on `NDEBUG`; release builds **will** trigger failures and crash.
- Throw a *custom* expression type whose constructor invokes `std::quick_exit`. This eliminates the need for `nothrow`.

  - Again, this won't be compiled out for release builds (unless you wrap the `quick_exit` call in `ifdef`'s).
- Wrap an actual `assert` inside a lambda, which is passed to a struct that takes an arbitrary callable (as a template parameter) and invokes it and then calls `std::quick_exit`, and then `throw` that struct. This one seems like severe overkill, but of course it generates a true assertion-failure message at runtime, which is nice.

  - This is the only approach that **will not** cause a release build to crash.
  - oliora provides a [variation of this approach](https://gist.github.com/oliora/928424f7675d58fadf49c70fdba70d2f) without the `throw` and the `quick_exit`. This seems much cleaner and saner.

Answer (score 1):

g++ is right. Per the standard, a non-static `assert` is not permitted in a `constexpr` statement.

> ... its function-body shall be a compound-statement that contains only:
>         null statements,
>         static_assert-declarations,
>         typedef declarations and alias-declarations that do not define classes or enumerations,
>         using-declarations,
>         using-directives,
>         and exactly one return statement.
>          -- 7.1.5/3

Comment: Ah yes, abort is also a return in a way. And clang may also be correct depending on the compiler options because assert may be just defined as noop.

Answer (score 1):

constexpr calculates in compile time. Non static assert in run-time.