# How to make sure in a constexpr function taking an array that the array is NULL-terminated?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, constexpr, null-terminated

The following code is meant to create sort of a trivial hash of a string up to 8 characters long:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t n=N>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<N<=9 && n==0,
uint64_t>::type string_hash(const char (&)[N])
{
    return 0;
}

template<std::size_t N, std::size_t n=N>
constexpr typename std::enable_if<N<=9 && n!=0,
uint64_t>::type string_hash(const char (&array)[N])
{
    return string_hash<N,n-1>(array) | ((array[n-1]&0xffull)<<(8*(n-1)));
}
```

For normal string literals and constexpr NULL-terminated strings it does indeed work normally. But if I do something like this:

```
constexpr char s2[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
std::cout << string_hash(s2) << "\n";
```

, the output will be the same as for the string `"\x1\x2\x3\x4\x5\x6\x7\x8"`. I've tried adding a `static_assert(array[N-1]==0,"Failed");` in the definition of `string_hash`, but the compiler says that `array[N-1]` is not a constant-expression. I then tried declaring the parameter `constexpr`, but the compiler said a parameter can't be declared `constexpr`.

How can I then do this check?

Comment: @CygnusX1: Those are not the inputs the OP is complaining about. Where did you get `"ugabuga"` from?

Answer (score 2):

Please keep in mind that although `constexpr` functions *can* be used at compile time, they don't need to be. You cannot add any static assertions on runtime parameters, because the static assertion would be impossible to evaluate when the parameters are not known at compile time.

What you can do is the same thing you can do for non-`constexpr` functions: throw something. This doesn't prevent your function from being called with invalid input, but does prevent silent wrong results. And when your function is used in a context requiring a constant expression, the compiler will correctly detect it as not returning a constant value.

The body of a `constexpr` function needs to be a single return statement in C++11, but you can still fit it in there:

```
return array[N-1] ? throw "bad!" : <your current return expression here>;
```

Do pick something better to throw though.

Comment: Throwing will print an error only at run time. An error at compile time would probably be preferable.

Comment: @CygnusX1 I already covered that in my answer. If the function is used in a context where a constant expression is required, and invalid input is passed, then it will be rejected at compile time. If the function is used in a context where a constant expression is not required, then there is no way to force the compiler to generate an error message. You link to pages involving `assert` in your answer. What do you think `assert` does when the condition evaluates as false? That won't cause any compilation failure either. There's just no way of doing that in C++.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the compiler is complaining is because the `array` is unknown at the time when `string_hash<N,n>` function is being instantiated. `static_cast` is evaluated when instancing, and not when invoking (even if it is constexpr function).

Notice that there will be exactly one function created for each pair of `<N,n>` values. If you use two constexpr strings of same length, exactly same instance of `string_hash` will be used, but depending on the argument `array[N-1]` may give a different result.

I will continue to search for a precise answer to your question if it is needed. However, as a "quick fix", may I suggest changing the hash function so that it always include the last character in the computation, be it 0 or not?

Update:
after doing some digging, I learned that some kind of `constexpr_assert` is what you probably want in your case and it is currently missing from the standard. Hopefully they will add it in the future. You may want to check:

- [g++ doesn't compile constexpr function with assert in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18648069/g-doesnt-compile-constexpr-function-with-assert-in-it)
- [Alternative to asserts for constexpr functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26072709/alternative-to-asserts-for-constexpr-functions)
- http://ericniebler.com/2014/09/27/assert-and-constexpr-in-cxx11